# How can I write my own isEmpty function so the typescript compiler knows a false result means the parameter IS defined?

Tags: typescript, types

I wrote this code:

```
export function myIsEmpty(input?: unknown): boolean {
  if (input === undefined || input === null) {
    return true;
  }
  if (input instanceof Array) {
    return input.length === 0;
  }
  return input == false;
}
```

As a rule, I tend to use `===` instead of `==`, so I hope that isn't invalidating my question.

I can write a passing unit test like this:

```
  it("empty", () => {
    expect(myIsEmpty(undefined)).toEqual(true);
    expect(myIsEmpty(null)).toEqual(true);
    expect(myIsEmpty([])).toEqual(true);
    expect(myIsEmpty('f')).toEqual(false);
    expect(myIsEmpty([1])).toEqual(false);
  });
```

The main take away being, if the parameter is "not empty," that means it is defined.

Yet, if I write code like this, it doesn't compile:

```
function example(): boolean {
  const input: string[] | undefined = undefined;
  if (myIsEmpty(input)) {
    return true;
  }
  return input.length > 0; //error
}
```

[image]

Is there any way to change my function so typescript understands `!myIsEmpty(input)` implies `input !== undefined`?  If not, why can't the compiler learn that?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLLKKm) work for your use cases? Control flow analysis doesn't cross function boundaries, but you can annotate boolean-returning functions with a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) for the purpose of narrowing one of the function arguments.  But there are caveats, so it really depends on use cases.  If the above code meets your needs I can write up an answer; otherwise, please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @jcalz It looks like it might work for my needs. What are the caveats in this case? I have never seen (or can't remember) that `is` keyword used after a return type. It's also confusing to me why you have that `input` on its own line in the middle. Can't tell if that's related to the bug you mention a few comments lower. I don't need that stuff explained to me in comments, just letting you know the gaps in my typescript type system understanding.

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.  For now though: The link above for "[type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)" will explain the `is` thing.  The `input` on its own line is just to show what the compiler thinks the type of `input` is at that place (you can hover over it to see that it has narrowed from `string[] | undefined` to `undefined`).  The bug is that it should really not eliminate an empty string, but that's a TS bug.

Comment: @jcalz ahhh, thank you

Comment: @jcalz oh right! I read about type predicates way back when I was learning typescript and forgot about it. I'll look out for places in my own code where I could use them

Comment: @DanielKaplan Why do you consider `[]` to be empty, but not `{}`?

Comment: @jsejcksn I just made this code up on the spot. It's more about learning about the type system then the implementation of that function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick answer to this question is that you want to annotate that `myIsEmpty`'s return type is a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) that serves to narrow the type of the `input` argument; that is, you want `myIsEmpty` to be a so-called *user-defined type guard function*.

---

When you perform checks or modifications on values of certain types, the compiler will use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to give these values more specific types:

```
function exampleInline(input: string[] | undefined): boolean {    
  if (input === undefined || input === null) {
    return true;
  }    
  if (input instanceof Array && input.length === 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return input.length > 0; // okay    
}
```

Here the compiler knows that in the last line of the function, `input` is definitely a `string[]` and not `undefined[]`.  It has eliminated the possibility that `input` might be `undefined` because knows that in such a case, the function would have already `return`ed.  That's exactly what you want.

But control flow analysis does not cross function call boundaries. See [ms/TS#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).  It would be way too expensive to try to follow such things.  So by taking an inline check and moving it out to a `myIsEmpty()` function will prevent the narrowing from happening.  Which is not what you want.

That's why user-defined type guard functions exist. So you want one of those.

---

Also note that control flow analysis works upon [assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) of a value to a variable of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  So any example code that looks like

```
const input: string[] | undefined = undefined;
```

is automatically telling the compiler that `input` is and will forever remain `undefined`, and no test, inline or otherwise, will convince the compiler that `input !== undefined`.  At best you can perform a test that convinces the compiler that `input` is [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).   So in all these examples I've changed things so that `input` is not initialized with a narrowed value, by making it a function parameter.

Okay, so we want `input` to be non-narrowed to start with, and we want `myIsEmpty(input)` to act as a type guard function on `input`.

---

Unfortunately there's not a perfect match between what your function deems as "empty" and types that TypeScript can straightforwardly represent in such a narrowing operation.  So you can do this:

```
function myIsEmpty(input: unknown): input is Empty {
  if (input === undefined || input === null) {
    return true;
  }
  if (input instanceof Array) {
    return input.length === 0;
  }
  return input == false;
}
```

but then you have to decide how to define `Empty`.  Clearly [`undefined` and `null`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined) are empty, and so is a zero-length array which can be represented as `[]`, the empty [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).  And we have to consider things that compare as ["equal to"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) `false`, which is a bizarre menagerie indeed.  There are the tame [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `false` or the numeric literals `0` and its bigint cousin `0n`. You've thankfully eliminated arrays, since `[[[0]]] == false` in JavaScript.  But you've still left "strings that can be coerced to `0`", meaning that `" \v \n -0.0e+10000 \n \r \t " == false`. Yuck.  There is no specific TypeScript type corresponding to those.  I'm going to give up and pay lip service to such strings by considering the empty string `""` and the one-character long `"0"` string to be empty, and everything else we'll just fail to deal with:

```
type Empty = undefined | null | "" | false | 0 | "0" | 0n | []
```

If you use this definition things will mostly work as you want, at least for your example:

```
function example(input: string[] | undefined): boolean {    
  if (myIsEmpty(input)) {
    return true;
  }
  return input.length > 0; // okay
}
```

There's no error here.  Let's see what is going on with it. When `myIsEmpty(input)` returns `true`, the compiler narrows `string[] | undefined` to `undefined`.  Now, technically, it should have narrowed to `[] | undefined` instead; the empty array is still possible.  This is unfortunately a bug in TypeScript, reported at [ms/TS#31156](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31156). So again, you could easily run into some friction here with what a type guard function can do for you here.  But since you don't really care about what happens in the `true` case, this particular example doesn't show any bad behavior.

In the last line, where `myIsEmpty(input)` must have returned `false`, the compiler has narrowed `string[] | undefined` to `string[]`.  And therefore you can check `input.length` with impunity.  Hooray!

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAogWwuGBeGBXAdgEygMwEssocYAfGLDAGxopgCJGH8BDGgZ1koAYHGvFnywMA2gF1gwfNgDGIQgHtRCMAElOiZGAAUxCBhAAuTFgDWWJQHcsASlMGjMQp3hIUAb2AwX+GPpYhiBoqOjYeEQkZOSUTiFh6NR0djDevr4ATlAgGJmiIJkYUADcPjAAvuWE-oHBLlicIGxYclBK-gCCmZlsYKnpGdm5+Q3BAHQ0UFgA5iAAFqHovGW+VVk5eaLxoTDsXKXAVcByKpxKU5NKM7pqmtrguowAtLzjvLxQANQATAAsvAAzIDGHZUgB6cEwQrFaSyVqKFQwJRKCCcXQDcrwhTKURQAAebCQU3UWBoxCgGNMACMUVMWmlpBkYKdGiF4qYmpliDNJAwIgQKWRwrhBdEyuVfPFJTBISyzuygkZTAKoqQmRkagEdokzJEhRQ4kqEmEqLQaJjmRsRgUiodmcdmXLWU0xsqqFAAG5QTIy4ZbN0gEq+OXWeZsAD8GuOx2xiLxhOJUFJ5JIdXdXJ5fMoqqFDhgtIuUAZ3mqtR1ptz0UNgaWZpSjOZ-tGMPtlTL2uNDSaLTaHRg3V6YBgADIR4HJtM5otdbxLUNNi27at2yGoS7FcFOYUs1JrQH4pPZgsYAA+GArWVQpTmPrSY4yeTxmAEokQKbpkwwTOzbN6sWkPmhb0qIpZSrUdxaB4ejxGCjaasaMrOgqgYqqKao4EhULZBwNDDgsrjfvMSi0GQ1KwLoVakOIEipNSzgLD6UBuGwMAACoAMoFhgMwwGwITzCAIBosYkIzIQCwYNS4ynAg4IIIQciZEo5z4CA4JsZAUAcUphDIOCricMUnDgoCACMZkAKwAGx+outrFCu6xXvKbKod+O6-nuMDNtsxpHtOZ4XhKD5AA)